# Exercise on Little $o$ and $\pi (x) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am trying to prove the following inequality involving $o(1)$.
$ X^8<M(X)^{1+o(1)} $ when X goes to infinity and where $ M(X)=e^{\pi(X)\log(\log X)}$ and $\pi(X)$ is the prime counting fonction .

My attempt is this.

By definition $o(1)$  means any function $f$ which goes to $0$ when $X$ goes to infinity, but by the $\epsilon $ definition we have that there exist some positive number $A$ s.t when $ x>A $  we get $|f(x)| <\epsilon$.

So to prove the above inequality it is enough to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $ X^8<M(X)^{1+\epsilon} $ as $\pi(X)$ is equivalent to $ X/\log X $ when $X$ goes to infinity.

We see that the RH growths exponentially which is faster than $X^{8}$ at infinity hence we get the desired inequality

Is this solution correct? If it is not how we can prove the above inequality?

Comment: "Grows exponentially" is not a precise term (or rather, if one made it precise, it would not quite hold in this case); so the given argument is not valid here.

Comment: X^8 grows much slower than exp(pi(x)) alone.

Answer (score 2):

There is one master lemma that everybody should know when looking at these types of functions:

**Lemma**. Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both tend to infinity. If $\log f(x) = o(\log g(x))$, then $f(x) = o(g(x))$.

(It's a good exercise to prove this lemma from the definitions, and to verify that the converse is false and also that the lemma would be false if $o({\cdot})$ were changed to $O({\cdot})$.)

Here it's easy to verify that $\log(X^8) = o\bigl( \log(M(x)^\delta) \bigr)$ for any $\delta>0$. We conclude that $X^8 = o\bigl( M(x)^\delta \bigr)$ for any $\delta>0$, so that we even have $X^8 =M(x)^{o(1)}$, which is much stronger than the given assertion.

Comment: But I didn't understand why $X^{8}=o(M(x)^{\delta}) $ Implies that $X^{8}=M(x)^{o(1)}$ ، can we prove that using the  definition of Little o

Comment: $X^{8}=o(M(x)^{\delta}) $ by Little o definition and by $\epsilon $ definition we get $ X^8<\epsilon M(x)^\delta $  taking $ \epsilon = 1 $ we get  inequality how did you get equality ?

Comment: $X^8 < M(x)^{\delta/2}$ implies $X^8 = o(M(x)^\delta)$. When we have these "for all small exponent" statements, $<$ and $O$ and $o$ are all equivalent.